# Division of power series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

Let $f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ and $g(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n$ in an open interval $(-r, r)$, and $g \neq 0 $ in $(-r, r)$. How can I prove that $h = f/g$ can be expressed as a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n$ that converges at least in $(-r,r)$?
I know how to 'calculate' the power series expansion of $h$, for example I can use the determinant method in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division. The question is, how can I prove that the series expansion 'does exist'(that is, converges)?

Comment: Note that $h=f/g$ is analytic in $|z|<r$ so has a power series with center $0$ which converges absolutely for $|z|<r$.

Comment: So my question is, how to prove that it is analytic. In the case of complex functions it is trivially differentiable so analytic but I'm studying real analysis.

Comment: Well $h=f/g$ is well defined for $|x|<r$ and one can prove that it is differentiable as many times as we need in that region. But I think proving convergence directly using coefficients also works. Try to prove that $1/g$ has a convergent power series and then use that multiplication of two power series also works fine.

Comment: Yeah, that is trivial too. I've already studied that the sum, difference or multiplication of power series is a power series so I can use them, but still the most difficult part is proving $1/g$ is a power series.

Comment: Do you know holomorphic functions?

Comment: Yes I do, but isn't it about complex valued functions?

Comment: Also I do not know very thoroughly about holomorphic functions, because I've studied complex analysis very roughly.

Comment: You should have a look at Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis* 2nd edition, page 238-239, Theorem 9.25 and Theorem 9.26 which deal with composition and reciprocal of power series. Maybe I will reproduce the relevant theorems and proofs as answer if I get time.

Comment: Thanks. I read those and understood it. But how can I prove that the radius of convergence is at least $r$?

Comment: It should be obvious from these two theorems. First we can assume without loss of generality that $r=1$ and $g(0)=1$. Then use $f(x) =1/(1-x)$ and $G(x) =1-g(x)$ and use the composition theorem on $f(G(x)) $ to get $1/g(x) $.

Comment: But doesn't Thm 9.26 say 'there exists a positive $\delta$'? It doesn't say anything about how big $\delta$ is.

Comment: And we need to make $\delta \geq 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a purely real analytic approach to finding the radius of convergence of the quotient of two power series, it would be interesting to see.  However, the only approach I know relies on Cauchy's formula, so it requires a bit of complex analysis. The fact that the radius of convergence is equal to the distance from the center of the expansion to the nearest singularity in $\mathbb{C}$, indicates some dependence on complex analysis.

Here is a proof that the power series for an analytic function has a radius of convergence equal to the distance from the center of the expansion to the closest singularity.

---

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n\tag1
$$
where $f$ is analytic inside, and continuous on, $B(r,z_0)=\{z:|z-z_0|\le r\}$. Set $\gamma=z_0+re^{i\theta}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1R
&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}\tag2\\
&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}\right|^{1/n}\tag3\\
&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm{d}z\right|^{1/n}\tag4\\[3pt]
&\le\frac1r\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: the [Cauchy–Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) (real analysis)
$(3)$: [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) (real analysis)
$(4)$: [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) (complex analysis)
$(5)$: $|z-z_0|=r$ on $\gamma$, the length of $\gamma$ is $2\pi r$, and $|f|$ is bounded

That is, $R\ge r$, where $f$ is analytic inside, and continuous on, $B(r,z_0)$.

---

Thus, if the series for $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ converge inside $B(R,z_0)$ and and $g(z)\ne0$ on $B(R,z_0)$, then both $f(z)$ and $1/g(z)$ are analytic inside $B(R,z_0)$, and neither have poles inside $B(R,z_0)$. Therefore, the series for $f/g(z)$ converges inside $B(R,z_0)$.

Comment: +1 there. I was waiting for someone to write this proof. Happy Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment and should be treated as such.

---

Well, it turns out that the radius of convergence of $1/g$ depends not only on that of $g$ but also on the region where $g$ does not vanish.

Consider $$g(x) =2-\cos x=1+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\dots$$ which converges everywhere so that radius of convergence is $\infty$. But its reciprocal $$\frac{1}{g(x)}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\dots$$ does not have radius of convergence $\infty $ but actually it is much smaller.

Why? We know that $g(0)$ is non zero and for real $x$ the value $g(x) >0$, but the reals don't count too much and we exactly need to know a number $R>0$ such that $g(z) \neq 0$ for all complex $z$ with $|z|<R$. Then the radius of convergence of $1/g$ will be at least $R$.

The theorems of Apostol's book also use complex numbers to deal with power series.

I am not very much familiar with complex analysis, but the key is that the idea of a function being expressed via power series in its region of convergence is completely equivalent to a function being analytic in a circular region. I hope there is some textbook available which describes analytic function theory starting from power series approach.

**Note**: This also explains the term *radius* of convergence as there is actually a circular region  of convergence in the complex plane involved. When restricting to real variables the only part seen is the interval of convergence and the term *radius* looks inappropriate for indicating the size of that interval.

Comment: Too many complex analysis textbooks confuse holomorphic, analytic and given by a single power series, whereas everything is about proving the equivalence of those 3 kind of functions.

Comment: @reuns: well said! Perhaps they leave the equivalence for the students to figure out for themselves once they attain some maturity.